# node.js http.connections

Tags: node.js

I am looking over node.js code and can't understand some of it.  Please help me with it.

```
var http = require("http"),
server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {});
......
if(MaxUserCheck <1 ){
server.watcher.stop();
logmsg(level1, server.connections);
}
```

For the above code,
what is "watcher" and how to use it?
"server.connections"   - what is this? and how to use it?

I have seen using server module as

```
server.on('request', function (req,res){};
...
server.listen(52273, function(){};
```

and I can understand as above, but using as "server.connections" can't understand and haven't seen it use like that.

I looked up on node.js manual but doesn't explain it.(http://nodejs.org/api/)
It seems that "server.connections" returns how many clients connected to our server..(Server uses Fugue for multi clients)
where can I find the usage of "server.connections" and "server.watcher"

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find that code? The `watcher` bit looks remarkably undocumented. The `connections` appears derived from [`net.Server.connections`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_server_connections_1)

Comment: Thank you sarnold. The code is in our server.  if it's net.server.connections ,   how come there is no net server moudule loaded?

Answer (score -1):

These two syntaxes might have been used/required in other directories.  If I export this module to a different file and say require('watcher') there , it will work.however I'm not sure what watcher is used but it could be [webwatcher](https://github.com/Seikho/watcher/blob/master/readme.md) module.